Create multi-range slider in Shiny
I have the follownig code:
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)
library(rCharts)

index <- as.Date(c(seq(Sys.time(), length.out = 1000, by = "days")))
dat <- data.frame(x = index,y = cumsum(rnorm(1000, mean = 0.1)))
dat <- xts(dat[,-1], order.by=dat[,1])

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(""),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("range_one", "Range One:",min = 100, max = 1000, value = c(200,300)),
      sliderInput("range_two", "Range Two:",min = 100, max = 1000, value = c(500,600)),width=3),
    mainPanel(
      column(12,dygraphOutput("dygraph"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$dygraph <- renderDygraph({
    dygraph(dat, main = "Data") %>% 
      dyShading(from = index[input$range_one[1]], to = index[input$range_one[2]], color = "#FFE6E6") %>%
      dyShading(from = index[input$range_two[1]], to = index[input$range_two[2]], color = "#CCEBD6")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

which produces the following output:

imagine now that I need to divide the graph into 4 zones, and that the end of one zone corresponds to the beginning of the next zone (with no gaps in between). For example, imagine that I need to divide the range of the slider into the intervals [100;300), [300;400), [400,500) and [500;1000].
Is there a way to create a single slider with 3 knobs, so that I can position them at values ​​300, 400 and 500 respectively, forming the 4 ranges I need?
